# Trying to parse value from json response in python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse specific values from a dictionary. That dictionary is a json payload from an API query. I've tried numerous ways but I'm just not able to get exactly what I want.

My goal is to:

1. Parse through a list of existing names. I have a blank dictionary that imports from a file.
2. See if that name is active per the API response.
3. print a list of active users: If user is active print ("User: %s is Active" % user)
4. Then print a list of inactive users: else print ("User: %s is not Active" % user)

To get the values I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import sys
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass()
url = "https://myurl/blah/blah/getusers=true"
request = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', password.format(password)), verify=True)

if(request.ok):
    data = json.loads(request.content)
    for key in data:
        users = data[key]
        print users
else:
  request.raise_for_status()
```

What is being returned:

```
https://myurl/blah/blah/getusers=true
getusers
users{u'max-results': 50, u'items': [{u'displayName': u'testfirstname, testlastname', u'name': u'testfirstname', u'self': u'https://blah/blah',               u'emailAddress': u'myemail@email.com', u'key': u'myusername', u'active': True, u'timeZone': u'America/Los_Angeles'},
```

I don't if it's just that I'm having trouble finding which key to get or what. The key in the response is:  **u'active': True**. I've tried to pull the 'active' value but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: more info. So, the payload returns a list of users with data for each user. The "active: True" is just one parameter that defines the user in the system. I want to take a list of users I already have and check the API to see if each user in my list is either "active: True" or "active: False". 
I'm not sure why the first two lines are returned (the url and getusers)

Comment: `json.loads()` will give you a nested dictionary. Inspect the keys at multiple levels to find what you want. I'd need a more specific question to say more - in fact I don't really know what you are looking for, or what your data looks like.

Comment: The dictionary output in your printout, what actually is that? Is that the whole response? You have 3 lines of output but only one `print` and I'm not sure what we're looking at there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like everything you want is inside the items level of the json.  Try something like this:

```
data = json.loads(request.content)
items = data['items']
active=[]
inactive=[]
for i in range(len(items)):
    user = items[i]
    if user['active']:
        active.append(user)
    else:
        inactive.append(user)
```

Comment: This gets me what I want, thanks. I just need to figure out how to compare the two dictionairies. When i try to print the list with print active.items(), i get an error.